# create case without an account dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

Can we create a case without any account or contact?

Comment: You need to be a little more specific: By which way do you want to create the case record? By manually filling the form? By client-side scripting? Server-side by a workflow or Plugin?

Comment: It is for an email-to-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way. Atleast a [dummy customer](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmsoftwareblog/archive/2016/09/14/service-case-customer-field-not-required-in-dynamics-crm-2016) (account/contact) is needed while creating case (incident).

If you see the customerid field customization, "System Required" will be the only option unlike other fields. This is to maintain real world scenario - an incident has to happen for a customer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a case from email, it will always link the sender to your created case. There is no way to unlink contact/account from the web interface. If you can explain more about your scenario, then I can suggest you some workaround if at all possible.

Comment: In the current customer service, a contact can be linked to several accounts or to no account. It is considered as an incident in any case. I want to know if there is a workaround to create an incident even if I don't have an account linked to the case but make the account required once the user open the case. Thank you

Comment: I am afraid this will not be possible because even if you create a case using SDK you have to pass account or contact otherwise you will receive an exception. You can create a dummy contact and then possibly delete the user however, this will have major data integrity issues and I would strongly suggest to avoid this method.